# Trying to get local weather

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I am trying to get local weather by getting `currentposition` and passing it to url for getting results. I can't seem to be able to pass the coordinates outside the `getCurrentPosition`.

My codepen is: http://codepen.io/rush86999/pen/MKMywE

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
//position.coords.longitude

var app = {

    getGeoLoc: function(id) {

        var self = this;

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

            var myVar1, myVar2, myVar3; // Define has many variables as you want here

            // From here you can pass the position, as well as any other arguments 
            // you might need. 
            self.foundLoc(position, self, myVar1, myVar2, myVar3);

        }, this.noloc, {
            timeout: 3
        });
    },

    foundLoc: function(position, self, myVar1, myVar2, myVar3) {
        this.latituide = position.coords.latituide;
        this.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        console.log('#4 position coords work in foundLoc: ', this.latitude, this.longitude);
    },
    latitude: '',
    longitude: ''

};

console.log('#5 found loc in app, ', app.foundLoc);

var url = 'api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' + app.latitude + '&lon=' + app.longitude + '&APPID=7bda183adf213c8cfa2ef68635588ef3';

//lets look inside url
console.log('#1 url has coordinates: ', url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Theres a few issues here.

- Firstly, you don't seem to be calling the `getGeoLoc` method, so that would be the first fix.
- You have included an error callback of `this.noloc` but it isn't included in your object.
- There are a few typo's for your co-ordinates
- You are making your API request before the geolocation has resolved so `app.latitude` and `app.longitude` will be undefined. This should ideally be wrapped in a method that gets called upon a successful geolocation request.

  ```
  var app = {

    getGeoLoc : function (id) {
        //Removed timeout option due to error
        var options = {}; //{ timeout: 3 };
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.foundLoc.bind(this), this.noloc, options);
    },

    foundLoc : function(position) {
      this.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
      this.longitude = position.coords.longitude; 
      console.log('coords ', this.latitude, this.longitude);
      // Call your get weather function
      // Using call to bind the context of `this`
      this.getWather.call(this);
    },
    // Error method
    noloc: function(err) {
       console.log(err.message);
    },
    // Method to get your weather after location is found
    getWather: function() {

        var url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' + this.latitude + '&lon='  + this.longitude +'&APPID=7bda183adf213c8cfa2ef68635588ef3';
        console.log('URL is: '+url);
        $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
          console.log('Your weather data', data);
          // Do your dom stuff here
        });
    },
    latitude: '',
    longitude: ''
  };

  // Make sure to call your initialising function
  app.getGeoLoc();
  ```

NOTE: I have removed the HTML stuff for the demo and have removed the timeout option as it caused an error.

[Link to forked codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bpbgyv?editors=0010)